# htmx: hx-trigger for a change event in a child element

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I use [htmx](//htmx.org) together with the Django forms library.

Here is my template:

```
<table>
 <tr hx-post="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" hx-swap="outerHTML" 
     hx-trigger="changed">
  <th>{{ object.leg.start }}</th>
  <th>--&gt;</th>
  <th>{{ object.leg.end }}</th>
  <th>{{ object.leg.distance }}m</th>
  <th>{{ object.leg.difficulty_verbose }}</th>
  <td>{{ form.runner }} {{ form.runner.errors }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the created html:

```
<table>
 <tr hx-post="/leg/155/Talfreunde/ %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="changed">
  <th>Schöneck</th>
  <th>--&gt;</th>
  <th>Mühlleithen</th>
  <th>13400m</th>
  <th>hard</th>
  <td>
    <select name="runner" required id="id_runner">
     <option value="">---------</option>
     ...
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want the `<tr>` to act like a form.

I tried to find a way to tell [hx-trigger](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/) to listen for the change event of the `<select>`.

How to tell htmx to submit the data as soon as the `select` was changed?

Background: This is a Relayrace and each leg will be a row in the table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `change` event. The term `changed` does mean something different.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.1.0"></script>

<table>
 <tr hx-post="//example.com" hx-trigger="change">
  <td>
    <select name="runner">
     <option value="a">a</option>
     <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works as intended for select elements. Is there a way to make this work for input elements too? Using hx-trigger="change" only triggers on blur, not on keyup.

Comment: @ndequeker I sugguest you asks a new question here at Stackoverflow. I can't dive into this at this moment.